# Jar Deployment - Correct Order Of Execution of Steps

Tags: java, performance, jar, obfuscation, jarsigner

I am using allatori as an obfuscation tool.

**I have 24 jars required for an Applet , so i found the steps to compress the Jars to minimize downloading time,**

> 1) Create uncompressed jars 2) Repack jars 3) Sign jars 4) Pack200
>   jars 5) finally apply LZMA to the file

**now i am confused where should i introduce obfuscation step 
I think it should be after 1 and before 2 , am i right ?**

What is the best way to accomplish my goal here in terms of order of the Task ?

can anyone explain of what order and why i should follow ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to my knowledge, you would obfuscate between 1 and 2. That will make the compiled class files smaller in size.

I am not really sure that this will help you gain a really big difference in size for your applet though.